# Merge of various slash tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

For some reason, there are currently six different tags for *slash* and *backslash*:

- [slash](/questions/tagged/slash) ×92
- [forward-slash](/questions/tagged/forward-slash) ×27
- [slashes](/questions/tagged/slashes) ×17
- [forwardslashes](/questions/tagged/forwardslashes) ×5
- [backslash](/questions/tagged/backslash) ×110
- [backslashes](/questions/tagged/backslashes) ×27

I think the first four should be merged into the dominant [slash](/questions/tagged/slash) tag, and the last two should be merged into the dominant [backslash](/questions/tagged/backslash) tag. Perhaps the merged tags should be replaced with synonyms so this doesn’t happen again.

Comment: I'm struggling to resist the temptation to retitle as: *Slash the slash tags!*

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121863/should-curly-brackets-and-curly-braces-be-merged-or-removed. The consensus seems to be either trash all punctuation tags or merge all similar punctuation into one tag. I think that both `backslashes` and `forwardslashes` come under the heading `slashes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plural variants are no more (manually edited into the singular variants, which had a lot more occurrences).

I've revised my position on whether to merge [backslash](/questions/tagged/backslash) and [slash](/questions/tagged/slash). Looking at the [slash](/questions/tagged/slash) tag now, most of the uses are about `/` and not `\`. The occasional misuse can be corrected by editors, and the correction would help the confused asker. So I now support using proper names:

- Make [forward-slash](/questions/tagged/forward-slash) a synonym of [slash](/questions/tagged/slash).
- Leave [slash](/questions/tagged/slash) and [backslash](/questions/tagged/backslash) as separate tags.

Answer (score 2):

Forward and backward slashes have very different uses. They happen to look similar and are sometimes used as paths separators but don't have much more in common than that. If somebody has the absurd idea to use a won sign ₩ as path separator, will you add that as a synonym?

You might argue that these are bad tags and should be eliminated in favor of a tag that describes the use (escaping, path separation,...), but merging `/` and `\` just because they look similar seems a bad idea IMO.

Comment: People who ask these questions often confuse the two (come on, how many times have you heard people refer to backslashes in URLs and slashes in (Windows) paths?). It's not about the use as path separator, it's about the visual confusion. Slash and backslash get approximately equal use (and misuse), so I don't see what harm merging would do.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see **strong** reasons to support back- and -forward-slashes separately (because questions about slashes anyway, yes?) and can imagine 6:1 collapse to [slash](/questions/tagged/slash), but your less radical idea also have rights to be implemented

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying here: *"you less radical idea also have rights to be implemented"*... Is it really radical to propose merging tags that have little to no independent uses?

Comment: @CodyGray - typo, "you*r* less radical". And excuse my poor English, you can seelct any other suitable synonym (and see at the content of proposal, not at form)

Comment: @CodyGray I think it is radical to merge tags which have little in common.