# Burninate [plus] and [minus]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

Do we really need the [plus](/questions/tagged/plus) and [minus](/questions/tagged/minus) tags?

They are either used for math, for the symbol somewhere in the question, or for concatenation. On almost all questions, they don't really add anything.

Comment: At the time of this writing, plus has 63 questions and minus has 83 questions. It does not seem to add any value (I can't imagine wanting to watch the `plus` tag). By the same token, [tag:hyphen] looks like it could go too.

Comment: [All](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/period) [of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curly-brackets) [the](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ampersand) [punctuation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tilde) [tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apostrophe) [must](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brackets) [die](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/square-bracket). [All](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/right-angle-bracket) [of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/questionmark)

Comment: [them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slash). [Even](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backslash) [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forward-slash). [And](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/addslashes) [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comma). [And](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quotes) [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-quotes).

Comment: @Emrakul wow that is a pretty deep rabbit hole you have there. Could you add those tags in an answer with a short description and perhaps the number of questions tagged like that. Bonus points for possible retag candidated so we can make an effort burninating them in one go.

Comment: @PeeHaa I've created an [offshoot question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207818/who-needs-punctuation-we-should-just-destroy-all-of-these-tags-now-can-we-please?noredirect=1#comment662190_207818).

Comment: @Emracool Related question [Merge of various slash tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126730/merge-of-various-slash-tags)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaand its'gone.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HsfL_JvFQE

Comment: Added the pair to my dead tags list.  Current count: **122**