# who needs punctuation we should just destroy all of these tags now can we please

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, burninate-request, tag-block-request

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207812/burninate-plus-and-minus) revealed to me a category of tags which serve no purpose, which are useless and ineffective, and which should be destroyed on the spot.

I kindly request that we retag/burninate all of the punctuation tags *and blacklist* most of them. Punctuation tags are very likely to return (somebody's going to use [period](/questions/tagged/period) again, you just know it), so blacklisting may be necessary.

"This isn't a problem." Isn't it?

[period](/questions/tagged/period) [curly-brackets](/questions/tagged/curly-brackets) [ampersand](/questions/tagged/ampersand) [underscores](/questions/tagged/underscores) [tilde](/questions/tagged/tilde) [apostrophe](/questions/tagged/apostrophe) [brackets](/questions/tagged/brackets) [questionmark](/questions/tagged/questionmark) [slash](/questions/tagged/slash) [backslash](/questions/tagged/backslash) [forward-slash](/questions/tagged/forward-slash) [comma](/questions/tagged/comma) [quotes](/questions/tagged/quotes) [double-quotes](/questions/tagged/double-quotes) [plus](/questions/tagged/plus) [minus](/questions/tagged/minus) [hyphen](/questions/tagged/hyphen) [parentheses](/questions/tagged/parentheses) [hyphenation](/questions/tagged/hyphenation) [colon](/questions/tagged/colon) [semicolon](/questions/tagged/semicolon) [dollar-sign](/questions/tagged/dollar-sign) [braces](/questions/tagged/braces)

*No longer living:* [right-angle-brackets](/questions/tagged/right-angle-brackets) [square-brackets](/questions/tagged/square-brackets) [underbar](/questions/tagged/underbar)

can we please kill the punctuation we should blacklist these it would make teh site soooo much better please can we

Comment: Also [underbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underbar) and [underscores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underscores).

Comment: @Kara [tag:underbar] has died.

Comment: I just found [braces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/braces)

Comment: You should also google around in case there's products called e.g. [Slash](http://slashcode.com/www.slashcode.com/)

Comment: @darvid I'm leaving [tag:slash] because that's not what the tag wiki reads.

Comment: > _"teh site soooo much better please can we"_. Okay...

Comment: There's also [tag:quote] (rename?) and [tag:smart-quotes] - related question - [Quote tags cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203973).

Comment: [tag:minus] is a SQL operator... not that I think it's generally used well.

Comment: @ben Compare [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minus+sql) with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minus); I agree, not a very good success rate.

Answer (score 3):

Hyphenation is the process of adding hyphens to printed words, using heuristics or a dictionary. So that one stays.

Checking [minus](/questions/tagged/minus), it appears to be used mainly as a reference to negative numbers. "Minus three" is colloquially equivalent to "negative three," even according to some public curricula. So that could be migrated to [negative-number](/questions/tagged/negative-number).

Those are the only two I clicked, but in general I don't see the issue. Spelled-out punctuation marks don't address specific issues in themselves, but combined with a language tag they do acquire meaning, and it's notoriously hard to do textual search for punctuation.

Many other common terms like [find](/questions/tagged/find) are the same. In my neighborhood of C++, punctuation marks even form names to identify generic functions.

Comment: The fact of this is, tags like these don't actually say anything about the question. If you see a question tagged [tag:c++], you know what the question is about. If you see [tag:sorting-algorithm], you know what the question is about. If you see [tag:double-quotes], it doesn't really help clarify the question, and doesn't serve as good metadata.

Comment: I think the point being made here is e.g. if a user wants to know what the period operator in objective-c actually *does*, they might search "objective-c period" or "objective-c dot". Having the question tagged [tag:period] might help in this case.

Comment: @Emrakul You're only speculating from ignorance. In fact, the 2011 revision of C++ introduced a new way of quoting double quotes. If someone asked "I have so many double quotes, how can I quote them more easily in C++?" then the answer would involve a new language feature created for exactly that use case. Likewise "javascript semicolon" *together* identify a specific, well-studied issue.

Comment: Ah, you're right. While I object to "You're only speculating from ignorance," @Potatoswatter, as I happen to have some experience with programming in a multitude of languages, I agree that there are edge-case uses of these tags.

Comment: Actually wait, no - Meta has had this discussion before. It doesn't matter if something couples with other tags to form meaning; if the tag doesn't have inherent, obvious meaning, it isn't good. I stick by my main post.

Comment: @Emrakul Also bear in mind that all questions are by policy required to have a language tag if possible. So such combination will essentially always happen.