# Proposed merge of [numeric] tag with [numerical]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I propose to remove the [numeric](/questions/tagged/numeric) tag and merge it with the
[numerical](/questions/tagged/numerical) tag. The reason is that I do not know what exactly [numeric](/questions/tagged/numeric) means
apart from the IMO correct [numerical](/questions/tagged/numerical) tag (there is neither an excerpt nor a
wiki). The discipline is called numeric*s*, the adjective is [numerical](/questions/tagged/numerical).

Comment: I'd propose that they'd be removed. They sound more meta than anything.

Comment: How do you tag then questions about rounding errors or numerical methods like root solver, numerical integration and optimization problems ?

Comment: Not everything _needs_ a tag for it. `[numeric]` or `[numerical]` does not work great as a standalone tag AFAIK... do you have a stronger case for why they are needed as-is? Right now, I'm looking at this in the same way like [how \[curly-brackets\] was for tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121881/150562).

Comment: How do you tag questions like: I am working on a game or simulation and I need to calculate a combination of functions (sin, cos, haversine) as fast as possible, but I need only e.g. 18 bits precision ? It is *not* a question of an [algorithm].

Comment: I believe you're describing [numerical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis).

Comment: I could see [numerical-analysis] working as a standalone tag. That sounds a lot better than [numeric] and [numerical] which is ambiguous. [numerical-analysis] is much more specific.

Comment: Good point. I see that there is also a strange [numericalupdown] tag ?! How about merging all numerical tags including numerical analysis to "numerical" ? It is shorter and I believe far less people know the term "numerical analysis".

Comment: @ThorstenS. But if someone's typing "numerical" in the tag box, "numerical-analysis" would appear as an option and the tag wiki would clearly demonstrate that it's what they're looking for. I think "numerical-analysis" is the proper tag to merge these into.